# ActiveRecord error when saving it to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I trying to save a id-number from a model like this:

```
x_value = Info.where("info_id='#{@infodata[:educationInfoRef]}'").select(:id)
```

In the terminal it returns correct, but when I save it to the db it saves the value like this: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f884b48c788>`

And when I print it from the terminal it returns nil.

Why? How can I saved the actual value?

I am using rails 3.

Comment: can you give more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first.  This code is prone to sql injection if @infodata was built using user input.  change your code to

```
x_value = Info.where(info_id: @infodata[:educationInfoRef]).select(:id)
```

Let's talk about your issue.  You forgot to call `.first` so it will return a record.  As an example, try this.

```
info = Info.where(info_id: @infodata[:educationInfoRef]).first
info.id # returns the id of the record
info.info_id # returns the value of @infodata[:educationInfoRef]
```